# property 'then' does not exist on type void, Angular 6 unit testing error

Tags: unit-testing, angular6, karma-runner

( angular 6 app, unit testing using karma and jasmine ) 
Hellooo,
Being new at unit testing, I tried http testing on one of my Service's functions by copying and pasting this code that i found in a tutorial :

```
let httpClientSpy: { get: jasmine.Spy };
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TrainerCalendarService } from './trainer-calendar.service';
import { asyncData } from '../helpers/async-observable-helpers';
import { Appointment } from '../models/appointment';

let service: TrainerCalendarService;

describe('Service: TrainerCalendar', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get', 'post']);
service = new TrainerCalendarService(<any> httpClientSpy);
 });

it('should returns list of appointment', () => {
const list: Appointment[] = [
  new Appointment(),
  new Appointment()
];

httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(asyncData<Appointment[]>(list));

service.getAll().then(items => expect(items).toEqual(list, 'same items'));
});
});
```

And i got this after changing it according to my app:

```
import { grpService } from "./app/Services/grp.service"; 
import { of } from 'rxjs'
import { EtudiantComponent } from './app/etudiant/etudiant.component';

let httpClientSpy: { get: jasmine.Spy };

let service: grpService;

describe('Service: Test attendency ', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get', 'post']);
service = new grpService(<any> httpClientSpy);
 });

 it('should returns list of students', () => {
 const list: EtudiantComponent[] = [
  new EtudiantComponent(service),
  new EtudiantComponent(service)
];

httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(of<EtudiantComponent[]>(list));

service.getGroupesFromServer.then(items => expect(items).toEqual(list, 'same items'));
 });
});
```

i get an error for that last line of code : Property 'then' does not exist on type '() => void'.

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Tried to make my way through, and it apparently worked by decomposing that line( where i got the error )  into multiple less complex lines of code :

```
httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(of<EtudiantComponent[]>(list));

let listres : EtudiantComponent[]; 
service.getGroupesFromServer(); 
let items = service.tabres ; 
expect(items).toEqual(list, 'same items');
```